# Vaadin UI components not display (liferay+vaadin)

Tags: apache, vaadin

I'm using Eclipse to develop an application using `vaadin (6.6.6)` and `apache tomcat-6.0.26`.

When a WAR folder is made, I can't find Vaadin folder inside.

Only `WEB-INF` and `META-INF` are there. This generates a bizarre layout (UI components are not visible, background color is white). When this version is deployed on another machine it generates an error on the apache but curiously it is running on the first machine (I mean with the incomplete layout).

Comment: You are missing the css style sheets, hence your webapp is displayed in white on white layout.

Answer (score 0):

You should update your widgetset, also set your widgetset directory in web.xml

```
<init-param>
<description>Application widgetset</description>
<param-name>widgetset</param-name>
<param-value>com.vaadin.sth</param-value>
```